# Can't use images in j2me application

Tags: java, java-me, midp, lcdui

I have some images in my application:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Form;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Image;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.ImageItem;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;

public class ImageCreateImage extends MIDlet {

    protected Display display;

    protected void startApp() {
        display = Display.getDisplay(this);

        Form form = new Form("Demo");

        form.append("line");
        try {
            Image red = Image.createImage("/red.png");
            form.append(new ImageItem(null, red, ImageItem.LAYOUT_DEFAULT, null));

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            form.append("Failed to load images");
        }
        display.setCurrent(form);
    }

    protected void pauseApp() {
    }

    protected void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
    }
}
```

but NetBeans gives an error:

```
[WARN] [rms     ] javacall_file_open: _wopen failed for: C:\Users\Win7\javame-sdk\3.0\work\0\appdb\_delete_notify.dat

[WARN] [rms     ] javacall_file_open: _wopen failed for: C:\Users\Win7\javame-sdk\3.0\work\0\appdb\00000002red-6png.tmp

javacall_lifecycle_state_changed() lifecycle: event is JAVACALL_LIFECYCLE_MIDLET_SHUTDOWNstatus is JAVACALL_OK
```

Comment: This information is not enough. Need some more information.

Comment: Sorry this is my first steps in stackoverflow

Comment: Where you are stored red.png?

Comment: Did you add that folder in Libraries and Resources on project properties?

Comment: I added it now but I stell have an error

Comment: Starting emulator in execution mode
Installing suite from: http://127.0.0.1:51683/ImportedProject-Slideshow1.jad
[WARN] [rms     ] javacall_file_open: _wopen failed for: C:\Users\Win7\javame-sdk\3.0\work\0\appdb\_delete_notify.dat

[WARN] [rms     ] javacall_file_open: _wopen failed for: C:\Users\Win7\javame-sdk\3.0\work\0\appdb\00000002icons#16#-Slideshow#2d#icon-6png.tmp

[WARN] [rms     ] javacall_file_open: _wopen failed for: C:\Users\Win7\javame-sdk\3.0\work\0\appdb\00000002icons#16#-Slideshow#2d#icon-6png.tmp

Comment: red.png file placed in inside of res folder(res/red.png). Right?

Comment: IT WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!! THANKS A LOT OF!!!!!!!! I changed Image red = Image.createImage("/red.png");
like this Image red = Image.createImage("res/red.png");

Answer (score 2):

Place the `red.png` image inside of res folder and add the res folder **Libraries and Resources** on project properties.